How to manage failing records when reading from Kinesis with Lambda
A Kinesis stream is the trigger for my Lambda. The Lambda reads the events, processes them, and writes them to S3. So far, so good. The problem arises when there is a failing event in that batch of reads.
How would you handle this issue?
I’ve considered the architecture to follow from here, but I have some doubts.

Resend the failed events back to the stream. I'm not entirely convinced about this approach because, in the same stream, there would be messages yet to be read, messages already read, and messages retried 1 or N times.

Set up a DLQ (Dead Letter Queue) in SQS to send the failed events. This is the standard option. However, I might have problems with the size of the events I’m sending, as SQS has a maximum size limit. If I were to follow this approach, it would be the same Lambda that reads from Kinesis that would receive the events from the SQS, with different logic in the code. Or should I use a different one?

This follows the same architecture as point 2, but instead of sending the failed event to SQS, it writes the event to S3, and sends an identifier of the event to SQS, so that the Lambda reads from S3 using this identifier. This way, I avoid the file size problem. However, I see this implementation harder to do.


In other words, the architecture for failed events would be:
kinesis ---- lambda --write and read-- S3
              
               | record identifier to read

              sqs

Which approach do you think is more correct? What pros and cons do you see for each one? What would be your solution?

your stream will continue to store the record even after failure (depending on your retention period). If you send the KinesisBatchInfo to a DLQ, it should be feasible to fetch the failed data from the stream at a later point:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg//kinesis-on-failure-destination.html
